# Probability of selecting 1 of i elements in a set of size n when choosing k elements

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Given a set of $n$ elements, I will choose uniformly at random $k$ distinct elements.

Given a set $S$ of $i$ distinct elements from $n$, what is the probability that at least one of the $k$ elements will be in $S$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to compute the probability that none of the $k$ elements will be in $S$, then subtract from 1.  $$1-\frac{{n-i\choose k}}{{n\choose k}}$$

Comment: So it turns out I'm actually interested in a second part--updated above.  I'm not sure how it affects the answer.

Comment: You should probably post that as a separate question.

Comment: Will do--thanks!